# Tengo un NULLPointer que no logro corregir

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

tengo e siguiente método el cual invoco desde MAIN:

```
public double distance(ArrayList<Puntos> array) {

    double acumulador = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= this.array.size() - 1 ; j++) {

        for (int i = j + 1; i < this.array.size() - 1; i++) {
            double dx = this.array.get(i).getX() - this.array.get(j).getX();
            double dy = this.array.get(i).getY() - this.array.get(j).getY();

            acumulador = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) + acumulador;

        }
    }
    return acumulador;
}
```

Cuando invoco el metodo me arroja un NullPointerException en la linea del for:
`for (int j = 0; j <= this.array.size() - 1 ; j--){`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Antes de entrar al  for(), verifica que el array recibido no sea null,

Comment: no te faltaria saber si el array viene null?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en la clase donde tienes el metodo `distance` tienes un atributo `array` el cual no esta inicializado por lo cual es null, entonces al usar this.array en el metodo haces referencia a ese atributo mas no al parametro de tu metodo, por lo cual deberias usar solo `array` o cambiarle de nombre para diferenciarlo y evistes confuciones.

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.